# How to get the selected item value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this custom combobox using div, how do i get the values inside combobox on click?

```
function selected_combobox(input) {
    $('#combobox').hide(); 
}
```

```html
<div id="combobox" style="" onclick="selected_combobox(this);" >
    <div>item 1 (i do not want to use onclick on each items)</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just give the "option" divs a class and bind click to to it

Comment: where do you store the selected value?  You typically have to know which one was clicked and store that value in a field or variable.

Comment: What value are you looking to retrieve? The inner divs only have text in them.

Comment: There are no values....You want to know what inner div was clicked? Use the event target.

Comment: value = innser divs text i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work using inline `onclick` javascript in your parent element cause when you click on it you get the entire element(parent div) as result. One solution is to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```js
// Get the element, add a click listener.
document.getElementById("combobox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // e.target is the clicked element!
  // If it was a div item
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "DIV") {
    //prints the text of the clicked element
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="combobox">
  <div>item 1 (i do not want to use onclick on each items)</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the event target, or utilize jQuery's delegated events which does NOT add events to all the divs. There is only one click event added to the parent.

```js
$("#combobox").on("click", "div", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="combobox" style="" onclick="selected_combobox(this);" >
    <div>item 1 (i do not want to use onclick on each items)</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="combobox" style="" onclick="selected_combobox(this);" >
    <div>item 1 (i do not want to use onclick on each items)</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

As per your markup, It's better to add a `selected` class to the selected item. Then whenever you want to retrieve the value, look for that class and get the value :)

```
$(function() {
    $("#combobox div").click(function() {
          $("#combobox div").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");         
          $(this).text(); // will give the value
    }); 
    // Now whenever you want to get the value then

     function getValueOfCombo() {
         return $("#combobox div.selected").text();
     }
});
```

In this approach, you can get the value of the combo box at anytime. Else in other appraoches, you will get the value only on click of that element.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the children divs using:

```
$("#combobox").children();
```

if you want the html/text you can use:

```
$("#combobox").html() // or $("#combobox").text()
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/children/

**EDIT:** Put this code inside your callback handler function.

**EDIT:** If you want child's (which was clicked) text, use:

```
$("#combobox").on("click", "div", function(){
    console.log($(this).text()); // or .html()
});
```

[You won't probably need the handler function for this]

Comment: Did I overlook something? Why the downvotes? I will happily admit my mistake provided I know what it is.

Comment: Down votes are probably related to the fact this is nothing like that the OP asked.

Comment: @epascarello As far as I understood, OP wanted "values inside combobox on click?" And I am doing that, right? Except that the code I am using is supposed to be within the onclick handler function OP is using. Probably this caused the confusion?

Comment: I think the issue is that your code will get the HTML/jQuery objects of the entire parent `div`, not the element which was clicked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see that comment by OP now. I am sorry for not seeing that. Thanks for clarifying.